# What is the correct way of retrieving data from associative arrays containing both numeric and string keys? Code sample with a weird issue below

Tags: php, json, serialization, associative-array

I'm developing a small module in php that takes a string containing a JSON-encoded array of stdObjects, decodes it, converts its objects to associative arrays and iterates over the result.

It is a straightforward process but I came across an uncommonly weird issue, even for php standards. For some reason I cannot read values for indexes greater than 9. I assumed there hade to be a types problem with those indexes, but I apparently ruled that out as shown on the code below:

```
$str = '{
   "2014": {
      "13": 0.03,
      "01": 0.03
   },
   "2013": {
      "13": 0.154,
      "12": 0.029,
      "11": 0.03,
      "10": 0.014,
      "09": 0.015,
      "08": 0.012,
      "07": 0.034,
      "06": 0.02,
      "05": 0,
      "04": 0,
      "03": 0,
      "02": 0,
      "01": 0
   },
   "2012": {
      "13": 0,
      "12": 0,
      "11": 0,
      "10": 0,
      "09": 0,
      "08": 0,
      "07": 0,
      "06": 0,
      "05": 0,
      "04": 0,
      "03": 0,
      "02": 0,
      "01": 0
   },
   "2011": {
      "13": 0,
      "12": 0,
      "11": 0,
      "10": 0,
      "09": 0,
      "08": 0
   }
}';
$variacion_mensual = json_decode( $str );
foreach( $variacion_mensual as &$var ){
    $var = (array) $var;
    echo 'Index as string: '."\t";
    var_dump( $var["13"] ); // Returns null
    var_dump( $var["10"] ); // So does this index
    echo 'Index as int: '."\t"."\t" ;
    var_dump( $var[13] ); // Returns null
    var_dump( $var[10] ); // So does this index
}
var_dump($variacion_mensual);
```

A weird problem deserves an equal-weirdness solution: beating php with php, so I tried this out and succeded:

```
foreach( $variacion_mensual as &$var ){
    $var = (array) $var; // Cast each object as stdObject
    // These two lines will do the trick
    $var = serialize($var);
    $var = unserialize($var);
    // These two lines did the trick
    echo 'Index as string: '."\t";
    var_dump( $var["13"] ); // Returns the correct strings containing the float info
    echo 'Index as int: '."\t"."\t" ;
    var_dump( $var[13] ); // Returns the correct strings containing the float info
}
```

Does anybody have a conjecture that explains this behavior? Thanks in advance for thy time and patience, I really home this is some of those off by one errors that are barely impossible for mortals to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
json_decode($str, true);
```

Point is, that `stdClass` objects don't implement `ArrayAccess` so you don't use them as arrays.

**OR**

If you want use them as objects try accessing:

```
$var->{"13"};
```